# PHP file upload

Tags: php, mysql, file, upload

I am trying to upload files to my server using php to save them into a binary form into my mysql database but I cant get it to work, here is the script I’m using, I believe it has something to do with "$_FILES" because when I take this out "&& $_FILES['userfile']['size'] >  0" the script starts to run but then the variables underneath that use "$_FILES" aren’t defined.

```
if(isset($_POST['upload']) && $_FILES['userfile']['size'] >  0) {
$fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
$tmpName  = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
$fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];

$fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
$content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
$content = addslashes($content);
fclose($fp);

if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
    $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
}

db_connect();
db_select();

$query = "INSERT INTO upload (name, size, type, content ) ".
"VALUES ('$fileName', '$fileSize', '$fileType', '$content')";

mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
db_disconnect();

echo "<br>File $fileName uploaded<br>";
}
```

Comment: Would be handy to check the output of var_dump($_FILES) to see exactly what's in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a 2 fold process, first the upload itself and then the manipulation on the server.  The first validation would be to make sure the file was even uploaded.  For that you can use after the line

```
$fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
```

Use:

```
if(is_uploaded_file($fileName)) {
  // Here goes all the file manipulation/storage/etc
} else {
  echo 'Error: File could not be uploaded.';
}
```

Try to use that and maybe re-post if the file was actually uploaded.  Just because $_FILES has content it does not necessarily mean that the file was uploaded to the server.

Answer (score 3):

You should better use the [file upload status](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php) to check whether the upload was successful.

And don’t use the `addslashes` function for MySQL queries. Use the [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you upload the files with a form, does it have a 'enctype="multipart/form-data"' in the "form" tag?

Answer (score 1):

I assume your field that's being posted is named "userfile"?

Also, this is not directly germane to your question, but it's generally considered a better practice to store files in the filesystem rather than in MySQL.  Filesystems are designed to store large blocks of binary data, while databases are not.

Comment: I was storing the files in a file system first off but tried this to make sure the error wanst something to do with the server not allowing uploads or something.

Answer (score 1):

I assume from your example that your input name is `upload`. `<input type="file" />` results in PHP are not sorted in `$_POST` but in `$_FILES`. The documentation uses `$_FILES['userfile']` as their example field, but if your input is declared as `<input type="file" name="upload" />`, you should simply use `$_FILES['upload']`.

Comment: Nope this is my form code:

<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000">
<input name="userfile" type="file" id="userfile">

Answer (score 0):

try make **print_r( $FILES )** and define what is the problem.
Maybe form have not needed type?